# Excluding specific files from Content Query

Tags: 2013, content-query-web-part, filter

I have a content query web part that displays all the latest documents added to a site collection but there are one or two occasions where a file will be uploaded that the user doesn't want advertised as uploaded.

People should still have their normal access to the file but it shouldn't be returned as a result in the Content Query Web Part on the main page.

Is there a way to flag specific files on upload/creation so that they don't get displayed in a CQWP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a new field to the document library, a Yes/No field.. asking user to select whether he wants the document to advertise or not.. Add a filter in Content Query Web Part for this field..

**EDIT**

**For multiple document libraries**

Approach 1:
Write a Powershell script to add this field to each document library.. Or using SharePoint Object Model add this field to document libraries..

Approach 2:
Make a site column i.e. Yes/No field, create a content type.. Add this field in the content type and make the document libraries to inherit this content type..

Either way you need to iterate all document libraries!

Comment: Is there a way that works for a number of libraries? This solution is good for one library but the site collection has several sites each with several document libraries. Would this field have to be added to each document library?

Comment: @DonaldDunlop see update on Answer